# How to enable VT extensions on a Dell inspiron 1545

Tags: virtualization, dell, bios, intel-vt-x

I am trying to install a centos virtual host on my ubuntu laptop but I cannot enable the VT extensions in the BIOS.

I have updated to the latest BIOS from Dell the processor is a core 2 duo so it definitely supports the VT extensions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some vendors, like Sony, for my Vaio, disable Intel VT and do not provide a BIOS option to turn it on, even though the processor supports it fine. I managed to [enable](http://www.wzzrd.com/2009/03/i-hacked-my-vaio.html) it on my Vaio, but not without a serious amount of research, luck and trouble.

If there is not option in your BIOS and you are sure your specific Core2Duo supports VT, complain at Dell Support and / or hope someone was able to binary patch your BIOS. I was lucky with the last option. Maybe there is such a patch for your BIOS too.

**UPDATE:** According to [post](http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=768456) in this thread the T6400 and T5800 does not support Intel VT. One of those is - according to Google - the processor in your laptop...

Comment: Agreed wzzrd, as far as I can tell none of the processors available on that model support hardware virtualisation.

Comment: thanks for the info I did not know that my processor did not support the extension I wrongly assumed all core 2 duos had the extension

Answer (score 4):

Which Core 2 Duo? Not all Core 2s have the VT extensions.

JR

PS See http://www.intel.com/products/processor_number/chart/core2duo.htm for a list of which Core 2's support VT.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the processor flags using [cpuinfo](http://gwenole.beauchesne.info/en/projects/cpuinfo) or grep "vmx" /proc/cpuinfo | uniq